# ng-if and ng-class-even/odd doesn't work well together and won't get expected outout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here,I am loading a json file and using ng-repeat I display json data into table form.I am adding following features to code.

1. checkboxes to add the two CSS:
     Bubble CSS 
     text-danger [In built class]
2. when you click on those check boxes, the CSS is applied only to the         even rows in the table.
3. Using the ng-if or ngHide/Show to display the User-info which have the gender :  Male.

I use **ng-if** to fulfill condition because **ng-if** will remove elements from DOM. This means that all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost.

ng-show/ng-hide does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements.

I created **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/dhwani91/pen/VKrwwY)** demo for my problem.Here ng-if and ng-class-even doesn't give expected o/p.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="module1" ng-controller="module1Ctrl as flight">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Angular app</h1>
</div>



<div class="checkbox">
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="danger">
    Something's Wrong
</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bubble">
       Zoom In/Out
    </label>
</div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
          <th>Birthdate</th>
           <th>gender</th>
            <th>father</th>

            <th>mother</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in flightData"
            ng-class-even ="{'text-danger':danger,'bubble': bubble}"
            ng-if="x.sex=='f'">
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.born |date:'yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss'}}</td>
          <td>{{x.sex }}</td>
            <td>{{x.father}}</td>
            <td>{{x.mother}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app=angular.module('module1',[]);
    app.controller('module1Ctrl', function ($scope,$http) {
         $scope.getDataFromServer = function () {
            $http.get('http://codepen.io/timivey/pen/emQZYY.js').then(
                function(res){
                    console.log(res.data);
                    $scope.flightData = res.data;
                }
                ,function (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                })
         };
        $scope.getDataFromServer();
        $scope.showList='table';
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small change to Joel's answer. You no need to create a separate filter method.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in flightData | filter:{sex:'f'}"
            ng-class-even ="{'text-danger':danger,'bubble': bubble}">
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but there is a small error with your understanding:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in flightData"
            ng-class-even ="{'text-danger':danger,'bubble': bubble}"
            ng-if="x.sex=='f'">
```

The `ng-if="x.sex == 'f'` statement is omitting each `<td>` from display, **but** it does not remove them from the `flightData` array. `ng-repeat` is run for each item in **the array**, not for each item that is displayed.

If you add `{{$index}}` to each row of the table you will see that the order is not `0,1,2,3...` it is `1,2,7,11,14...`

If you remove the `ng-if` statement, you will see that every even row has correct class applied.

Instead of using `ng-if` to remove the males from the list, use a `filter` instead:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in flightData | females"
            ng-class-even ="{'text-danger':danger,'bubble': bubble}">
```

Append this filter to your controller statement in the JS code:

```
.filter('females', function() {
      return function(input) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(x) {
          if(x.sex == 'f') {
            out.push(x);
          }
        });
        return out;
      };
  })
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mABJyo

What this does is remove the males from the list **before** it runs the ng-repeat and will correctly output in the order `0,1,2,3...`

Comment: Hey That was a good alternative solution .Thanks @JoelCDoyle.